# How can I fake ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

How can I fake an ObjectContext when unit testing?  I have created my generic repository that excepts an ObjectContext, faked the ObjectSets, but I can't figure out how to create and pass a fake ObjectContext containing the fake ObjectSets into my repository.  My repository accepts a class of type ObjectContext.

Any ideas?

```
public class FakeObjectSet<T> : IObjectSet<T> where T : class {
    HashSet<T> _data;
    IQueryable _query;

    public FakeObjectSet(){
        this._data = new HashSet<T>();
        this._query = this._data.AsQueryable();
    }

    public void AddObject(T Item) {
        this._data.Add(Item);
    }
    public void Attach(T Item) {
        this._data.Add(Item);
    }
    public void DeleteObject(T Item) {
        this._data.Remove(Item);
    }
    public void Detach(T Item) {
        this._data.Remove(Item);
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return this._data.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public Type ElementType {
        get { return _data.AsQueryable().ElementType; }
    }
    public Expression Expression {
        get { return _data.AsQueryable().Expression; }
    }
    public IQueryProvider Provider {
        get { return _query.Provider; }
    }
}
```

My fake objectset implementation

```
public class FakeJobSet : FakeObjectSet<Job>{
}
```

and my fake context class:

```
public class FakeCentralRepositoryContext{
    public FakeCentralRepositoryContext(){
        this.Jobs = new FakeJobSet();
    }

    public IObjectSet<Job> Jobs
    {
        get; private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be aware of huge differences between mocked and real behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332002/how-to-mock-the-limitations-of-entityframeworks-implementation-of-iqueryable/13352779#13352779.

Answer (score 1):

Your repository cannot accept instance of `ObjectContext` - you must define your custom interface implemented by both you real derived context and fake context. Your repository must accept that interface. Anyway faking contexts is [waste of time and completely bad approach to testing code using EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766478/unit-testing-dbcontext).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your repository to take IObjectSet rather than ObjectSet then you can pass your fake context into the repository the same way you pass in the real implementation. Alternatively, use a IOC to inject the context.

Comment: Do you mean pass in a IobjectSet into the repository's constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I would **avoid faking/mocking ObjectContext** as this object [presents complex inner workings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332002/how-to-mock-the-limitations-of-entityframeworks-implementation-of-iqueryable/13352779#13352779), and to do so, defeats the purpose of relying on [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) for taking care of the data layer abstraction.

Check out the post at [How to mock ObjectContext or ObjectQuery in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415432/how-to-mock-objectcontext-or-objectqueryt-in-entity-framework/18645613#18645613) for a better approach to do unit tests with EF.

Hope this helps!